# How to get the modification date of a file in Racket?

Tags: racket

I need to determine what has changed in the file system.

How can I a get the time when a file was last modified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The modification time of a file will always be returned by [`file-or-directory-modify-seconds`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Filesystem.html?q=file%20date%20modify&q=ch/wa&q=patch-lift&q=raw&q=serve/ser&q=serve/ser&q=%23%3Amanager#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._file-or-directory-modify-seconds%29%29). This will also return the modification date of directories except from the FAT format file systems - for directories a FAT file system will return the creation date instead.

To convert the file modification time, or any time in seconds to a more readable format you can use [`seconds->date`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/time.html?q=seconds-&q=file%20date%20modify&q=ch/wa&q=patch-lift&q=raw&q=serve/ser&q=serve/ser&q=%23%3Amanager#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._seconds-~3edate%29%29).

```
> (require racket/date) ;for date->string only
> (date->string
    (seconds->date
      (file-or-directory-modify-seconds
        (string->path "/home/ben/.emacs"))))
"Wednesday, June 4th, 2014"
```

reference: [racket discussion list](http://lists.racket-lang.org/users/archive/2014-June/063089.html)